# How to use MSBuild proj files for packaging the bits in Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 using Visual studio Build definition

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, msbuild-task

I am trying to build the project using Visual studio build, the build is happening fine, but now I want to package the bits i.e (package and configuration files) for that I am using a MSBuild proj files but how to give it as input to VS build in Visual Studio Team Foundation Server.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible using VSTF 2015 .
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/vs/define-build